# Simple way to navigate through bootstrap nav pills

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav-pills

I have a bootstrap nav pills [sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/nq0uxgqx/) drawn as,

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sec1"><b>Section 1</b></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sec2"><b>Section 2</b></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sec3"><b>Section 3</b></a></li>
</ul>
```

I can go to next tab once user clicks on next button inside the tab content by using jquery as [given here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/nq0uxgqx/1/). Is there any other simplest way rather than this example using angularjs or any other methods?

Comment: Where is the angular/js?

Comment: @Satej That is what I asked is there any better ways using angularjs or something other methods. Myself used jquery in my sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class `.next` to the next buttons and work from the tab id and href:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    var tab = $(this).closest('.tab-pane');
    $('#' + tab[0].id + ', .nav-pills li').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-pills li a[href="#' + tab.next()[0].id + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    tab.next().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 0px;">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sec1"><b>Section 1</b></a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sec2"><b>Section 2</b></a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sec3"><b>Section 3</b></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sec1" class="tab-pane active">
          <p>Section 1 tab 1</p>
          <div class="text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm next">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sec2" class="tab-pane">
          <p>Section 2 tab 2</p>
          <div class="text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm next">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sec3" class="tab-pane">
          <p>Section 3 tab 3</p>
          <div class="text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```